# Can Windows 7 double nest environment variables?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

In the GUI:

```
WORK_HOME=D:\work
LOG_HOME=%WORK_HOME%\logs
FOO_LOG_HOME=%LOG_HOME%\foo
```

On command line:

```
echo %LOG_HOME%
D:\work\logs
```

but

```
echo %FOO_LOG_HOME%
%LOG_HOME%\foo
```

The only difference is that the variable used in %FOO_LOG_HOME% uses another variable (%LOG_HOME%) that also uses another variable (%WORK_HOME%) whereas %LOG_HOME% uses a variable that is set to a literal value (%WORK_HOME%).

Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: I am not doing "set commands". The top of the post says that I am setting the said vars in the GUI

Comment: My bad! I missed the use of the GUI part.  I'd be curious to know if you get different results if you *don't* use the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Windows processes environment variables at logon in alphabetical order.  Any variables nested in the right-hand side will be expanded if they are already set.  If not set , the nested variable reference is likely to be stored "as is", complete with percent signs.

Since `%WORK_HOME%` is pretty far down the alphabet, it is not defined when those other variables are processed.

The only workaround I know of is to use variable names that are alphabetical by order of expansion.

There does appear to be some attempt in Windows 7 to improve upon this, but it does not appear to be reliable enough to trust:

```
>REG QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment | FINDSTR AUSR
    AUSRA    REG_SZ    alpha
    AUSRB    REG_EXPAND_SZ    bravo %AUSRA%
    AUSRC    REG_EXPAND_SZ    charlie %AUSRB%
    AUSRD    REG_EXPAND_SZ    delta %AUSRC%
    AUSRI    REG_EXPAND_SZ    india %AUSRJ%
    AUSRJ    REG_EXPAND_SZ    juliet %AUSRK%
    AUSRK    REG_EXPAND_SZ    kilo %AUSRL%
    AUSRL    REG_SZ    lima

>SET AU
AUSRA=alpha
AUSRB=bravo alpha
AUSRC=charlie bravo alpha
AUSRD=delta charlie bravo alpha
AUSRI=india %AUSRJ%
AUSRJ=juliet %AUSRK%
AUSRK=kilo lima
AUSRL=lima

>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

>
```

Comment: If envars are processed in alpha order, why does `LOG_HOME=%WORK_HOME%\logs` work, since `%WORK_HOME%` would be the last envar set according to the OP's example?

Comment: Hmmm, good point.  Might be one is set in System environment, the other in User.  I suppose it could also be that the registry has a value set to REG_SZ and not REG_EXPAND_SZ.  OP, you around to try any troubleshooting?

Comment: My guess is that even though the the list is sorted alphabetically in the GUI and CLI interfaces, they're probably processed in the order in which they happened to get stored in the registry, but I haven't confirmed this. That just seems to be Microsoft's MO in a lot of cases.

Comment: I went through this a few years ago on some Vista systems, and it was definitely alphabetical there.  I suppose I should double-check on Win 7 just in case it changed.

Comment: OK, did some testing, edited answer to reflect.  It seems that there is **some** attempt by Microsoft to allow for non-alphabetical nested expansion, but it seems limited and idiosyncratic (as noted, that describes most of what Microsoft does).